# Sanitizar comilla simple con PHP?

Tags: php, filtro

deseo sanitizar exclusivamente la comilla simple, pero esto de forma global en mi proyecto para todos los $_POST.

Solía utilizar estas lineas para depurar html:

```
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

¿Existe algúna vertiente que se encargue de solo ese caracter (comilla simple) o alguna idea para realizar una función que aplique para arreglos o valores enviados a través de $_POST?

*Gracias por su apoyo.*

Comment: en resumen tu problema es?